# Krita: how to add imported image to a layer mask

Tags: layers, mask, krita

I need to add an imported image mask to a transparency mask layer. I'm currently using Photoshop in my workflow and can import image masks created in blender and create layer masks with them, but cannot figure out how to do it in Krita.

Answer (score 3):

You can import the file as transparency mask by doing these steps:

1. Select the layer you want to have the mask applied and then go to `Layer menu > Import/Export > Import > Import as transparency mask` (the white portion of your image will reveal the parts of the layer)
2. Import the image to the layer stack by going to `Layer menu > Import/Export > Import as paint layer`. Then keep this newly imported layer below the layer you want to add this image as mask, and then right click on the mask image and go to the convert section and click on convert to transparency mask.

Comment: I was adding a file layer and then adding my desired image file in... Above steps depict the correct approach.